# ManifestPlaceholder val cannot be reassigned in defaultConfig

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, sdk, auth0

I am new to **android** development (as well as development in general) and wanted to make **authentication** using **Auth0**.

So I am following [this guide](https://auth0.com/blog/android-authentication-jetpack-compose-part-2/) as well as [this guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android/interactive).

Both of them tell that I need to add this line of code:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain", auth0Scheme: "@string/com_auth0_scheme"]
```

to `defaultConfig` block in `build.gradle` file. So `defaultConfig` should look something like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain", auth0Scheme: "@string/com_auth0_scheme"]
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }

    }
```

However, this new line of code results in various **errors**, as following:

**1. manifestPlaceholder** gives **"Val cannot be reassigned"** error.

**2. auth0Domain** gives **"Unresolved reference: auth0Domain"** error.

**3. auth0Domain**  gives **"Expecting ']'"** error

**4.** There is also **"Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)"** error.

I checked **github repo** for their **demo app**, and this line of code is **present** there as well.

Tried to find an **answer** to this but **failed**. Also tried to change values, but that didn't **help** either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions tell you about `build.gradle` which is a Groovy DSL build script.

But you have a `build.gradle.kts` which is a Kotlin DSL build script.

That is like if you try to paste Python code into a Java file.

How to properly do it in Kotlin DSL depends on what you want to achieve, you could for example use

```
manifestPlaceholders.clear()
manifestPlaceholders["auth0Domain"] = "@string/com_auth0_domain"
manifestPlaceholders["auth0Scheme"] = "@string/com_auth0_scheme"
```

or

```
addManifestPlaceholders(
    mapOf(
        "auth0Domain" to "@string/com_auth0_domain",
        "auth0Scheme" to "@string/com_auth0_scheme"
    )
)
```